# Matching Regex in For Comprehensions

Tags: scala

I am using Scala 2.9 to process some Excel files. They are all stored in a directory and have the filename `Sales_yyyy_mm.xlsx`.

I wrote the following code, to produce an array with the year, month and `File` of each Excel:

```
val fileStruct = """Sales_(\d\d\d\d)_(\d\d).xlsx""".r

val excels = (new java.io.File(dirName)).listFiles

val files = for(file <- excels; fileStruct(year, month) <- file.getName)
            yield(file, year, month)
```

The array of files is computed correctly into `excels`. However `files` is empty. I have checked the file names and they all match the regex (if I rewrite my code using `match`/`case` there is no problem).

The code compiles correctly and the types are inferred as I expect them, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `file.GetName` returns a `String` -- or, from the for-comprehension's point of view, a `Seq[Char]`. Now, when you use a pattern matching in a for comprehension, you are applying a filter before mapping or flatMapping. In effect, you are doing this:

```
  val files = excels.flatMap(
    (file => file.getName().withFilter(
      ((x$0 => x$0 match {
        case fileStruct((year @ _), (month @ _)) => true
        case _ => false
      })).map(
        (x$1 => x$1 match {
         case fileStruct((year @ _), (month @ _)) => (file, year, month)
      }))))
```

The problem is that `x$0` is a `Char`, so it will never match the regex pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I made it work in the following way:

```
val fileStruct = """Sales_(\d\d\d\d)_(\d\d).xlsx""".r

val excels = (new java.io.File(dirName)).listFiles

val files = for{
                file <- excels
                year :: month :: _ <- fileStruct.unapplySeq(file.getName)
            }
            yield(file, year, month)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only have Sales_yyyy_mm_xlsx on your directory, try this :

```
scala> val files = for(file <- excels ; val fileStruct(year, month) = file.getName)
     | yield(file, year, month);
```

and if not :

```
excels.map(file => fileStruct.findFirstIn(file.getName) match {
     |  case Some(fileStruct(year, month)) => Some(file, year, month)
     |  case _ => None
     | }).filterNot(_.isEmpty)
```

give me :

```
res3: Array[Option[(java.io.File, String, String)]] = Array(Some((./Sales_2012_03.xlsx,2012,03)), Some((./Sales_2012_04.xlsx,2012,04)))
```

I think the problem appear when the regexp doesn't match

Comment: yyyy stands for the year and mm for the month. I have several of those files in the directory. I have tried your suggestion but get a MatchError